# import file from same directory using "sys.path.append" in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook, sys

I am using Jupyter Notebook. I tried to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64683853/jupyter-cant-find-python-imports-in-same-directory) question which was really close to my problem, but I couldn't picture the directory tree of the questioner, so I couldn't apply the answer as well.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68107899/cannot-import-file-from-same-directory), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885445/import-python-module-using-sys-path-append) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453834/importing-files-from-a-directory-without-using-sys-path-append-or-sys-path-inser). Applied all the solutions but no luck.

**My directory tree:**

The path from home to training_single_neuron:

home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron

```
── training_single_neuron

    ├── activation.py.ipynb

    ├── bias.ipynb

    ├── Car maintenance cost prediction.ipynb

    ├── Cost_function.py.ipynb

    ├── first_network.py.ipynb

    ├── flowerdata.py.ipynb

    ├── flower.py.ipynb

    ├── Gradient_descent.ipynb

    └── Normalization.ipyn
```

In flowerdata.py I stored all the data. I want to use data in flower.py. I tried to import flowerdata in flower.py. But, I always get an error messages.

**The ways I tried:**

1.

```
import flowerdata as data
```

error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flowerdata'

2.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron")
from training_single_neuron import flowerdata
```

error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'training_single_neuron'

3.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron")
from training_single_neuron import flowerdata
```

error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'training_single_neuron'

4.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron/")
from training_single_neuron import flowerdata
```

error: No module named 'training_single_neuron'

5.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron")
from training_single_neuron.flowerdata import data
```

error: No module named 'training_single_neuron'

I get the same error, does not matter in what way I try to import.

I tried to print the path in sys included using;

```
sys.path
```

It seems like my directory path is included several times

Output shows:

```
['/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron',
 '/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron/',
 '/home/pc/installed-programs/pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/pc/installed-programs/pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/pc/installed-programs/pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron/',
 'home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron/',
 'home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron',
 'home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron',
 'home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron',
 '/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron',
 '/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron/',
 '/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron/',
 '/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron',
 '/home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron',
 'home/pc/python-projects/deep_learning/training_single_neuron']
```

What I am missing here? Could anyone please help me to understand the issue?

Comment: Those are notebooks, not modules.

Comment: THe data you want to import needs to have a `.py` extension.  You cannot import from notbook files or those with an `.ipynb` extensioin

Comment: @Alexander I got the point. Is there any way I could use .ipynb file in other .ipynb file?

Comment: @Alexander thank you for giving me hints. The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. As .ipynb is not a module but notebooks. Importing any module as I tried in several ways does not work. To import a notebook we need to use below code.

```
%run flowerdata.py.ipynb
```